# Laravel "Class name must be a valid object or a string"

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to add comments after posts in my laravel app. I found this package https://github.com/laravelista/comments which i wanted to use. I installed it, and followed the instructions, the issue that i get now is

> Class name must be a valid object or a string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\vendor\comments\components\comments.blade.php)

and it shows me this code:

```
    {

        return tap(new $class, function ($instance) {

            if (! $instance->getConnectionName()) {

                $instance->setConnection($this->connection);

            }

        });

    }
```

this code was not written by me, but generated after I installed the previously mentioned package.

My Post.php file is here:

```
namespace TicketSystem;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravelista\Comments\Commentable;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Commentable;
    protected $table = 'posts'; //default?
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true; //default

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TicketSystem\User');
    }
}
```

and my User.php file is here:

```
namespace TicketSystem;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;
use Laravelista\Comments\Commenter;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, Commenter;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('TicketSystem\Post');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('TicketSystem\Role');
    }

    public function hasAnyRoles($roles) {
        return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first();
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($role) {
        return null !== $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
    }
}
```

in the blade.php file where I wanted to add comments:

```
<div>
     @comments(['model' => $post])
</div>
```

how to solve this problem? I searched a lot on how to but it wasn't very successful.

EDIT:
comments.php file:

```
return [

    /**
     * To extend the base Comment model one just needs to create a new
     * CustomComment model extending the Comment model shipped with the
     * package and change this configuration option to their extended model.
     */
    'model' => \Laravelista\Comments\Comment::class,

    /**
     * You can customize the behaviour of these permissions by
     * creating your own and pointing to it here.
     */
    'permissions' => [
        'create-comment' => 'Laravelista\Comments\CommentPolicy@create',
        'delete-comment' => 'Laravelista\Comments\CommentPolicy@delete',
        'edit-comment' => 'Laravelista\Comments\CommentPolicy@update',
        'reply-to-comment' => 'Laravelista\Comments\CommentPolicy@reply',
    ],

    /**
     * The Comment Controller.
     * Change this to your own implementation of the CommentController.
     * You can use the \Laravelista\Comments\CommentControllerInterface.
     */
    'controller' => '\Laravelista\Comments\CommentController',

    /**
     * Disable/enable the package routes.
     * If you want to completely take over the way this package handles
     * routes and controller logic, set this to false and provide your
     * own routes and controller for comments.
     */
    'routes' => true,

    /**
     * By default comments posted are marked as approved. If you want
     * to change this, set this option to true. Then, all comments
     * will need to be approved by setting the `approved` column to
     * `true` for each comment.
     *
     * To see only approved comments use this code in your view:
     *
     *     @comments([
     *         'model' => $book,
     *         'approved' => true
     *     ])
     *
     */
    'approval_required' => false,

    /**
     * Set this option to `true` to enable guest commenting.
     *
     * Visitors will be asked to provide their name and email
     * address in order to post a comment.
     */
    'guest_commenting' => false,

    /**
     * Set this option to `true` to enable soft deleting of comments.
     *
     * Comments will be soft deleted using laravels "softDeletes" trait.
     */
    'soft_deletes' => false

];
```

In PostsController file:

```
    * Display the specified resource.
    * 
    * @param int $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

   public function show($id)
   {
      $post = Post::find($id);
      return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
   }

   /**
    * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
    * 
    * @param int $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

   public function edit($id)
   {
      $post = Post::find($id);
      if (auth()->user()->id !== $post->user_id) {
         return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized Page');
      }
      return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
   }
```

dd($post, $id) shows:

```
  #table: "posts"
  +primaryKey: "id"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
"11"
```

{{ dd($post) }} in edit.blade.php

```
  #table: "posts"
  +primaryKey: "id"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your config is cached. Re-cache your config and it should work.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This package has its own config file, and uses the `mergeConfigFrom()` method. This method was changed in Laravel 6.x to not merge configs when the config is cached.

So, if your config is already cached when you install this package, the package configuration will never be loaded until you re-cache your config after installing the package.

Since the package config is not being read, the `config('comments.model')` config value will be empty, and you'll get the error you're seeing.

One general note: when you have an issue with a package, check the Github issues for that package. Someone may have already run into it, and there might be a solution. For example: https://github.com/laravelista/comments/issues/103. Now, that "solution" is way overboard, since they didn't exactly know what the issue was, but it would have worked for you (the call to `php artisan optimize` re-caches the config).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of newbies like myself, if you are getting the error in deployment and you wonder how to delete the config in the cache, do the following;

```
sudo rm (YOUR PROJECT PATH HERE)/bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

on ubuntu server

Comment: You can delete your config cache with `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your cache

```
php artisan config:cache

composer dump-autoload
```